# .NET core 3.1 novell.directory.ldap doesn't get all LDAP users

Tags: .net-core, ldap

I am developing an application based on .NET Core (3.1) which is connect to Active Directory to get the users.
I use Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard 3.6.0.
I have more than 4000 users but I got just about 800 users.

LDAP MaxPageSize is 5000, and when I try using System.DirectoryServices I got all users.
but I have to use Novell because I need to publish the application on docker.

```cs
var ldapConn = new LdapConnection { SecureSocketLayer = false };
ldapConn.Connect(domainName, 389);
ldapConn.Bind(username, password);

ILdapSearchResults lsc = ldapConn.Search("OU=myOU,DC=domain,DC=com",
    LdapConnection.ScopeSub, "(objectClass=person)", null, false);

CSV WriteToCSV = new CSV();
while (lsc.HasMore())
{
    nextEntry = lsc.Next();
    LdapAttributeSet attributeSet = nextEntry.GetAttributeSet();
    if (attributeSet.ContainsKey("sAMAccountName"))
    {
        string result = attributeSet.GetAttribute("sAMAccountName").StringValue;
        WriteToCSV.WriteToCsv("Persons.csv",);
    }
}
```

> Error: Size Limit Exceeded

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem by using "SearchUsingSimplePaging" function

```
var ldapConn = new LdapConnection {SecureSocketLayer = false };
         ldapConn.Connect(domainName, 389);
         ldapConn.Bind(username, password);
                
         SearchOptions options=new SearchOptions("OU=my_OU,DC=domain,DC=com",LdapConnection.ScopeSub,"(objectClass=person)",null);
         var searchResult=ldapConn.SearchUsingSimplePaging(options, 1000);

         CSV WriteToCSV = new CSV();
         foreach (var ldapEntry in searchResult)
         {
             dapAttributeSet attributeSet = ldapEntry.GetAttributeSet();


             if (attributeSet.ContainsKey("sAMAccountName"))
             {
                 string result = attributeSet.GetAttribute("sAMAccountName").StringValue;
                 WriteToCSV.WriteToCsv("Persons.csv", result);
             }
         }
```